# Undefined reference when installing BLAS-3.7.0 package

Tags: fortran, gfortran, undefined-reference, blas

I'm new to Linux, so I try to setup a virtual machine on Oracle VirtualBox to work with Ubuntu 14.04 -32bit version. I downloaded BLAS-3.7.0 package from http://www.netlib.org/blas/ and install it by first compiling all the .f file with gfortran:

```
    gfortran -c *.f
```

then creating a shared library with all the compiled file:

```
    sudo gfortran -shared -fPIC  -o libblas.so *.o
```

When I checked the shared library with

```
    nm -u libblas.so
```

It returned a list of undefined reference like those:

```
     U cabsf@@GLIBC_2.1
     U cabs@@GLIBC_2.1
     w __cxa_finalize
     U _gfortran_stop_string@@GFORTRAN_1.0
     U _gfortran_string_len_trim@@GFORTRAN_1.0
     U _gfortran_st_write_done@@GFORTRAN_1.0
     U _gfortran_st_write@@GFORTRAN_1.0
     U _gfortran_transfer_character_write@@GFORTRAN_1.4
     U _gfortran_transfer_integer_write@@GFORTRAN_1.4
     w __gmon_start__
     w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
     w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
     w _Jv_RegisterClasses
     U sqrtf@@GLIBC_2.0
     U sqrt@@GLIBC_2.0
```

I then tried to add the math library of glibc and the gfortran library like some suggestion with -lm and -lgfortran:

```
    sudo gfortran -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8 -shared -fPIC  -o libblas.so *.o -lm -lgfortran
```

but the same error returns.

I would be very grateful if somebody can help me point out the problem of my shared library. I need the BLAS and LAPACK package to install GPAW simulation library (https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/) but GPAW always sends back the error message due to the undefined references while linking with BLAS and LAPACK shared library.

Edit: *********
For GPAW-1.2.0, I install it using static library of BLAS-3.7.0, lapack-3.7.0 and libxc-3.0.0 by modifying the extra_link_args in the setup.py file:

```
    extra_link_args ['/usr/local/lib/xc/lib/libxc.a', '/usr/local/lib/BLAS-3.7.0/libblas.a', '/usr/local/lib/lapack-3.7.0/liblapack.a']
```

My configuration.log file after installing GPAW look like this:

```
    libraries []
    library_dirs []
    include_dirs ['/usr/local/lib/xc/include', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include']
    define_macros [('NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API', 7)]
    extra_link_args ['/usr/local/lib/xc/lib/libxc.a', '/usr/local/lib/BLAS- 3.7.0/libblas.a', '/usr/local/lib/lapack-3.7.0/liblapack.a']
    extra_compile_args ['-Wall', '-std=c99']
    runtime_library_dirs []
    extra_objects []
```

I also add the library path and include path into LIBRARY_PATH and C_INCLUDE_PATH:

```
    echo $C_INCLUDE_PATH 
    /usr/local/lib/xc/include/
    echo $LIBRARY_PATH 
    /usr/local/lib/BLAS-3.7.0:/usr/local/lib/lapack-3.7.0:/usr/local/lib/xc/lib
```

I then installed it with:

```
    sudo python setup.py install >&log.txt
```

when I try to run a test script in gpaw/test folder, or simply just typing "gpaw info" in the terminal window, it returned this:

```
    OpenBLAS : Your OS does not support AVX instructions. OpenBLAS is     using Nehalem kernels as a fallback, which may give poorer performance.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/gpaw", line 2, in <module>
    from gpaw.cli.main import main
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpaw/__init__.py", line 239, in <module>
    from gpaw.calculator import GPAW
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpaw/calculator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import gpaw.mpi as mpi
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpaw/mpi/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from gpaw.utilities import is_contiguous
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpaw/utilities/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    import _gpaw
   ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_gpaw.so: undefined symbol: dnrm2_
```

I guess the openblas warning come from the fact that I installed numpy on my machine through

```
    sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

but I did not select openblas in my install configuration.

Comment: Show us the exact error message when you link wiith GPAW. The library is not supposed to include symbols from other libraries, they are loaded from them when running the final executable.

Comment: And also the exact command that caused the error message.

Comment: Thanks, It changes quite a few things quite importantly. Do you have OpenBLAS installed? Or is it in GPAW? Where does it come from? Maybe your own BLAS does not play any role at all.

Comment: I actually looked at the config.py in gpaw-1.2.0 source code and look at the i686 configuration for 32-bit machine. I modified it a bit to avoid automatic  findings of openblas shared library and blas or lapack shared library (because I want to install with both blas-3.7.0 and lapack-3.7.0 static library

Comment: When did you modify it? Now or before the error? If before the error, the god knows what actually happens...

Comment: I did try to install gpaw without modifying anything from the config.py and setup.py (and have my openblas package installed). It automatically find openblas shared library from what I checked on the confiuration log. It did not work and return some undefined error like I mentioned above. I then get rid of openblas package (because of that I guess openblas message warning come from python-numpy package), modify the config.py to avoid automatic finding of shared library, downloaded BLAS and LAPACK package and install on my own, point to these static library and run setup.py, still got error.

Comment: Actually I might try to re-install gpaw without changing anything (with or w/o openblas package and post it here for you.

Comment: Hi again Alexander. It did work now :) I don't know why but I re-downloaded the package and only add libxc static library, I let blas and lapack shared lib automatically found and it did work. I will check the function to see i any problem arise but thanks a lot for your suggestion.